# Passing Data between views in Adobe Flex (Actionscript)

Tags: apache-flex, view

Ive read a ton of online tutorials about this and cant seem to get a definite answer...

**View1.mxml**

```
navigator.pushView(views.view2, {response:"BLAH"});
```

**View2.mxml**

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    var result:String = // FIRST VIEW RESPONSE WHICH = BLAH

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

How is this done? Surely it should be simple? All the tutorials online seem very indepth!
Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

```
navigator.pushView(views.view2, "BLAH");

var result:String = String(data);
```

Duhhh

Answer (score 1):

The property you are looking for is called `data`.  It will get set AFTER construction.  So, once `data` is set, you want to access `data.response`.